# How to config Nuxt.js runing on ie 11

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I using `Nuxt.js @ v2.13.2` and I try to config my project working with `ie 11`

The doc say:

```
The default targets of @nuxt/babel-preset-app are ie: '9' in the client build, and node: 'current' in the server build.
```

Here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```
build: {
    babel: {
      presets({ isServer }, [ preset, options ]) {
        // change options directly
        options.buildTarget = 'client'
        options.targets = {
          ie: 11,
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And my pages

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

But it not working in `ie 11`

```
[object Error]{description: "Syntax error", message: "Syntax error", name: "SyntaxError", number: -2146827286, stack: "SyntaxError...", Symbol(amplify_default)_i.icdaor5bqh3: undefined, Symbol(extensions)_k.icdaor5bqh3: undefined, Symbol(observable)_j.icdaor5bqh3: undefined, Symbol(react.element)_h.icdaor5bqh3: undefined
```

How to do that thank.

Comment: does this error appear in dev modus or production modus?

Comment: @Ifaruki i just update message error. It seem errors from amplify lib :(

Comment: Are you adding [polyfills](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) with Symbol support?

Comment: @yqlim yes, i added `import "core-js/stable"; import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"` but still get error

Comment: Can you confirm if `Symbol` is correctly [polyfilled](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-symbol) ?

Comment: @yqlim sorry late, I imported `import "core-js/stable"` but not working

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the issue is that the Symbol polyfill does not and cannot support cross-realm native functionality.

More detail here: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/834